# float tag down left without breaking word

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9S8O.png)

I would like the "NODEJSasdfasdfasdf" tag to float down let on the line underneath if there is not enough width left. How can I do that?

I expect this to happen:

```
PYTHON EXAMPLE              |
NODEJSasdfasdfasdf          |
```

As opposed to this:

```
PYTHON EXAMPLE NODEJSasdfasd|
fasdf                       |
```

or this:

```
PYTHON EXAMPLE NODEJSasdfasdfasdf
                            |
```

---

Note that there could be eg. 8 tags and so it might be the 3. and 5. tag that needs to pushed down left onto the line underneath.

---

css

```
ul#mix-wrapper {
    ul {
        padding: 0;
    }

    list-style: none;
    //word-wrap: break-word;

    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .card-tags ul {
        margin-block-start: 12px;
        margin-block-end: 12px;
        float: left;
    }
    .card-tags ul li {
        display: inline;
        width: fit-content;

    }
    .tag {
        background-color: #989898;
        margin: 4px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
}
```

pug

```
li.mix.catC
    div test3
        .card(style='width: 18rem;')
            img.card-img-top(src='/images/pug3.jpg', alt='Card image cap')
            .card-body
                p.card-text
                    | C
                .card-tags
                    ul
                        li.tag PYTHON
                        li.tag EXAMPLE
                        li.tag NODEJSasdfasdfasdf
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you can style the last li display to block content and clear both sides from floating like that:

```
.card-tags ul li:last-child {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Hope it solve it.

Read about last-child pseudo element here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: It should only be pushed down onto a new line if the tag is longer than the div containing it. It would be a waste of space if I did it to all the last tags in each card no matter its length. All in all, this is not a good solution. Note that there could be 8 tags and so it might be tag 3 and 5 that needed to pushed down left onto the line underneath.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment is need to be part of the original question.